# how to find each of week of day then add up the numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, lookup

I have this excel: (for example)

| fri, jul 1 | sat, jul 2 | sun, jul 3 | mon, jul 4 | tue, jul 5 | wed, jul 6 | thur, jul 7 | fri, jul 8 | sat, jul 9 | sun, jul 10 | mon, jul 11 | tue, jul 12 | wed, jul 13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $10 | $20 | $30 | $15 | $18 | $14 | $24 | $74 | $68 | $45 | $88 | $77 | $49 |
| total of sundays | today of mondays | total of tues | total of wed | total of thurs | total of fris | total of sat | (empty) | (empty) | (empty) | (empty) | (empty) | (empty) |

What I like to do is find each of the week of days (from row1), then sum all its numbers below them (row 2).

in this case, based on the sample table provided:

```
sum of all suns: 75

sum of all mons: 103

sum of all tues: 95

sum of all wed: 63

sum of all thur: 24

sum of all fri: 84

sum of all sat: 88
```

anyway I can do this without the manual calculations?

Comment: sorry, year was 2022.

Comment: Is row one text or actual dates? In that case you can sum by using something like `SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(A1:M1)=1)*(B1:M1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find unique week days:

```
=UNIQUE(TEXTBEFORE(A1:M1,","),1)
```

To get sums:

```
=BYCOL(UNIQUE(TEXTBEFORE(A1:M1,","),1),LAMBDA(z,SUM((TEXTBEFORE($A$1:$M$1,",")=z)*($A$2:$M$2))))
```

Result:

[image]

If you need to start it by Sunday then sort array.

Or manually write weekdays in row 3, add this formula to A4:

```
=SUM((TEXTBEFORE($A$1:$M$1,",")=A3)*($A$2:$M$2))
```

And drag it right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do dynamically spill an array - <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> is not required :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>O2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:M2,,1),2),
     b,TEXTBEFORE(INDEX(a,,1),", "),
     c,SORT(HSTACK(b,XMATCH(b, 
     {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"}),INDEX(a,,2)),2),
     d,INDEX(c,,1),
     e,UNIQUE(HSTACK("Sum of all "&d,MMULT(N(d=TOROW(d)),INDEX(c,,3)))),e)
```

---

If you need the header, then add a <kbd>VSTACK( )</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:M2,,1),2),
     b,TEXTBEFORE(INDEX(a,,1),", "),
     c,SORT(HSTACK(b,XMATCH(b, 
     {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"}),INDEX(a,,2)),2),
     d,INDEX(c,,1),
     e,UNIQUE(HSTACK("Sum of all "&PROPER(d),
     MMULT(N(d=TOROW(d)),INDEX(c,,3)))),VSTACK({"Weekdays","Total Sum"},e))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:M2,,1),2),
     b,TEXTBEFORE(INDEX(a,,1),", "),
     c,SORT(HSTACK(b,XMATCH(b,{"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"}),INDEX(a,,2)),2),
     d,INDEX(c,,1),
     e,UNIQUE(HSTACK("Sum of all "&PROPER(d)&":"&
       TEXT(MMULT(N(d=TOROW(d)),INDEX(c,,3)),"_($* #,##0_)"))),
       VSTACK("Weekdays"&":"&"Total Sum",
     e))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Up By Weekday

[image]

```
=LET(sData,A1:M2,slRow,1,srRow,2,
        dData,{"su";"mo";"tu";"we";"th";"fr";"sa"},
    dl,TOROW(dData,,3),
    sl,LEFT(INDEX(sData,slRow,),LEN(@dl)),
    sr,INDEX(sData,srRow,),
    dr,BYCOL(dl,LAMBDA(c,
        SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(sr,sl=c,0),"")))),
dr)
```